# Jelly Bean's Offline Voice Typing APK

Tags: voice-recognition

Is this possible to get Jelly Bean's Offline Voice Typing apk for other Android versions like Gingerbread or ICS???

Comment: Possible? Maybe. The source code for Jelly Bean has only recently been released. If the voice typing isn't too deeply baked into the OS someone will likely soon port it out for other versions. I wouldn't hold out much hope, though.